# How to say "It was fun to have been able to go there" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

Which of these sentences is correct? and why?

> - そこに行くことができた楽しかった
> - そこに行くことができて楽しかった

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself? Do you understand て-form? Can you chain together two past-tense predicates?

Answer (score 1):

そこに行くことができて楽しかった is correct. the 楽しかった at the end makes the whole sentence past tense. you could also say そこに行けて楽しかった to make it a bit more casual.

Rather than 楽しかった Japanese people tend to use よかった to show they were happy to have been able to go there/do something. so then it would become そこに行けてよかった.